# how to assign the loaded txt/xml file's array to variables?

Tags: xml, variables, actionscript, text, load

I use following flash actionscript code, got from online, to load the "Loading.txt" file:

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
 myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded); 
 function onLoaded(e:Event):void { 
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/,","); 
} 
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("Loading.txt"));
```

In "Loading.txt", the data of object in a row is (Dim1 Dim2 Dim3 OX OY OZ) is:
60,12,9,-50,-50,50
84,12,9,  50, 50,50

Then I use onLoaded[i-1][j-1], in a loop to get the data in row i and column j of the array, but I got some error message. Can somebody help me on this? I am totally new to actionscript. The loop I used is like
var ArrayRows:int=2 // how to automatically get the number of rows of the txt file?

```
for(iObj=0;iObj<ArrayRows;iObj++){
    Dim1 = ObjDimArray[iObj][0]
    Dim2 = ObjDimArray[iObj][1]
    Dim3 = ObjDimArray[iObj][2]

    OX = ObjOriginArray[iObj][3]
    OY = ObjOriginArray[iObj][4]
    OZ = ObjOriginArray[iObj][5]
}
```

Also, seems most people recommend using xml and I compiled an xml file "Loading.xml" for above "Loading.txt" as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<All>
<Equipment Num="1">
 <Manufacturer>HW</Manufacturer>
 <Length>60</Length>
 <Width>12</Width>
 <Thickness>9</Thickness>

 <OriginX>-50</OriginX>
 <OriginY>-50</OriginY>
 <OriginZ> 50</OriginZ>
</Equipment>

<Equipment Num="2">
 <Manufacturer>HW</Manufacturer>
 <Length>84</Length>
 <Width>12</Width>
 <Thickness>9</Thickness>

 <OriginX>50</OriginX>
 <OriginY>50</OriginY>
 <OriginZ>50</OriginZ>
</Equipment>
</All>

I used following code to load the "Loading.xml". I would like to use a loop to read all values and assign to a variable. Can anybody teach me how to do that?

var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "Loading.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
trace("Data loaded.");
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

With Actionscript E4X, you do not have to reassign XML values to a variable unless it is continuously being used; and even then, its to preserve the ui thread.

Expanding on your loader method, the following may be used as example as to accessing the data contained in the XML:

```
var equipment:XMLList = xml.Equipment;

var idx:uint;
var item:XML;

for(idx=0; idx<equipment.length(); idx++)
{
    item = equipment[idx];
    trace
    (
        "\n" + "Item(" + item.@Num + "):\n" +
        "Manufacturer:", item.Manufacturer + "\n" +
        "Length:", item.Length + "\n" +
        "Width:", item.Width + "\n" + 
        "Thickness:", item.Thickness + "\n" +
        "OriginX:", item.OriginX + "\n" +
        "OriginY:", item.OriginY + "\n" +
        "OriginZ:", item.OriginZ
    );

}
```

You could take this a step further, if you assume all equipment elements have id's through the "Num" attribute, direct access to the data would be as follows:

```
var myData:XMLList = xml.Equipment.(@Num == 2);
trace(myData.Manufacturer);
```

Beware, that the above code will grab all "Equipment" elements with the attribute Num == 2.  You can still access the Manufacturer node however, if there are multiple Equipment tags contained in the "myData" result, you will have multiple Manufacturer nodes returned in an XMLList.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. I still got error messages using following codes:

Comment: Dim1 = trace(myXML.Equipment[iObj].Length);
    Dim2 = trace(myXML.Equipment[iObj].Width);
    Dim3 = trace(myXML.Equipment[iObj].Thickness); OR  Dim1 = trace(myXML.Equipment.(@Num==iObj).Length);
 Dim2 = trace(myXML.Equipment.(@Num==iObj).Width);
 Dim3 = trace(myXML.Equipment.(@Num==iObj).Thickness);  The error message says Error # 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number. I defined variables var Dim1:Number;
var Dim2:Number;
var Dim3:Number;

var OX:Number;
var OY:Number;
var OZ:Number; Do you know why? Thanks...